# Tricky exercise about finding the inverse function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined as $f(x)=2x-3$. Is not hard to check out this function is injective but it is not surjective. So the function has at least one left inverse . By doing a simple math I have that $f^{-1}:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Z}$ defined as $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{x+3}{2}$ we have that $f^{-1}f=I_{\mathbb{Z}}$. The problem is that the function $f^{-1}$ is not so well defined since $f^{-1}$ is not always in $\mathbb{Z}$, for example for $2 \in \mathbb{R}$ we have that $f^{-1}(2)=\frac{5}{3} \notin \mathbb{Z}$. How can I properly find a left inverse of this function? Thanks

Comment: well if you just need a function G such that G(f(x)) returns you back x, then what you have should work. the case where f(x) = 2 doesn't seem to matter because the original function f will never map to 2.

Comment: Ok, I dont have problem understanding your accurate observation. But Im still conflictated since the inverse have $\mathbb{Z}$ as codomain and $\mathbb{R}$ as domain, so the function is still well defined for every number in the domain if im not composing with $f$. :(

Comment: tbh this just seems like an odd way to define f from the get go ... but i think what Ted is saying is to find a function, h, to compose with f inverse such that it forces every input value x in R to arrive in Z. so if f inverse = G and then find G(h(x)) such that h(x) forces the new input to G to arrive in Z.

Comment: Got Ted idea with the help of your comment but still I dont find such h or $\phi$ you and Ted are proposing :(

Comment: well the function h(x) will have as domain R and we want it to map where? we want it to map to only values that don't cause you frustration like x = 2 did in your original post.... all the while not changing values x input values that were not problematic to begin with and that G can already deal with on its own.

Comment: There is another problem with h you are mentioning, because h:R -> Z and G goes also from R to Z, so how the compositions is having sense?

Comment: Z is a subset of R

Comment: Still im not getting the exercise guys but Im truly trying to understand. Sorry, its probably me. Seems like those exercises I need to see another look.liker exercises in order to get it .

Comment: Im giving up guys, sorry :(

Comment: @Cos: I wasn't involved in any of this discussion. I was thinking of something like $\phi(x) = \lfloor x\rfloor$, the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$. So if you do $\phi(f^{-1}(x))$ for your function $f^{-1}$ you'll end up with a function mapping to $\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

If your function did work you'd have a right inverse as well. The standard way out of this is to define the function differently at those $x$ for which $\frac{x+3}2$ is not an integer. Alternatively, do you know a function $\phi\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb Z$ which has the property that $\phi(n) = n$ whenever $n\in\Bbb Z$? Maybe you could compose $\phi$ with your alleged $f^{-1}$.